# Why am I getting an unexpected string when using .format to slice list?

Tags: python-3.x, slice

I am trying to create a game of rock, paper, scissors. However, when I try to .format a string inside of an input function using a slice I am getting the following:`Choose Rock, Sciss or Scissors:`

I am using the following script:

```
options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

def rock_paper_scissors():
    x = ''
    for option in options:
        if x == '':
            x += option.title()
    else:
        x += ', ' + option.title()

    player = input('Choose {} or {}:'.format(x[0:11], x[-8:]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the slicing that's going wrong, it's the string construction. You should indent the `else:` block a bit more. For reference, try `print()`-ing `x` before your input command.

#### What happened

Python `for` loops can have an `else:` clause. These are executed unless a loop is terminated by `break` or `return`. Therefore, your loop only did something on the first iteration while x was still an empty string, and then the else clause would modify your string with the `option` still bound from the last iteration of your loop.

#### Edit

Perhaps I'm a bit to used to Code Review, but I'd suggest doing the construction differently, more like this:

```py
player_move = input(f"Choose {', '.join(options[:-1])} or {options[-1]}")
```

Do note, though, that this will only work for a 3+ length for options. To get a fitting string for less options requires a more... elegant construction.

Comment: ahh, of course! I should have spotted that. I'm curious to know why it stll Many thanks!

Comment: I'm curious to know why `print()`-ing `x` results with: `Rock, Scissors` I don't know why it wouldn't just be: `Rock` as I thought it would only assign one iterator after my `if` statement, moreover, why did it skip `Paper` and go straight to `Scissors`?

Comment: Thank you for your edit by the way, I will look into constructing the script using this construct.

Comment: Python `for` loops can contain an `else:` clause. This is executed when loops aren't terminated by a `break` or `return`. Inside the loop, something only happened the first iteration while `x == ""`. After the loop `option` was still bound from the last iteration, so that added "scissors" in the `else:` clause.

Comment: I see, an easy to understand and concise explanation. Thank you.